# Cannot access Inputs from my controller/constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple Angular 2 component with `@Input`, which I bind to the template. The template shows input data, but I cannot access it from the constructor:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap, Input} from 'angular2/angular2';
import DataService from './data-service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-cmp'
})
@View({
    template: `{{data.firstName}} {{data.lastName}}` //-> shows the correct 'data'
})
export default class NamesComponent {
  @Input() data: any;
  constructor(dataService: DataService) {
    console.log(this.data);//undefined
  }
}
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pOAZQK?p=preview) with an example (see "names-component.ts").

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Because the `Input` property isn't initialized until view is set up. According to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), you can access your data in `ngOnInit` method.

```
import {Component, bootstrap, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import DataService from './data-service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-cmp',
    template: `{{data.firstName}} {{data.lastName}} {{name}}`
})
export default class NamesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data;
  name: string;
  constructor(dataService: DataService) {
    this.name = dataService.concatNames("a", "b");
    console.log(this.data); // undefined here
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data); // object here
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on the newer api, you actually need to import OnInit from "angular2/angular2", and then change your class to implement OnInit so it should look like:

export default class NamesComponent implements OnInit {
...
}

Comment: This answer still works with 2.0.0-beta.8. So a service can be initialized in the constructor ( constructor(dataService: DataService) { this.dataService = dataservice}). But the actual fetching of the service using the input as an argument would need to happen within the ngOnInit() function (using something like ngOnInit() {var data = this.dataService; this.dataService.getData(data).subscribe...

Comment: @Harrington Darkholme i did thesame but could not solve my issue can i tag you on my question

Comment: With Angular 9 (and maybe previous versions as well) this answer does not work anymore. Use `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook instead of `ngOnInit` to access `@Input()` decorated properties.

Comment: Processing the data to fill a table on the UI keeps giving me the dreaded `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` though.

Answer (score 7):

You must implement OnChanges, see below:

```
import {Component, bootstrap, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import DataService from './data-service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-cmp',
    template: `{{data.firstName}} {{data.lastName}} {{name}}`
})
export default class NamesComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() data;
  name: string;
  constructor(dataService: DataService) {
    this.name = dataService.concatNames("a", "b");
    console.log(this.data); // undefined here
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.data); // object here
  }
}
```

Comment: For Angular 9 (and maybe previous versions as well) this should be the accepted answer. Properties decorated with `@Input()` are undefined inside `ngOnInit()` but defined within the scope of `ngOnChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

[The way to access your data per documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) is to write a setter and a getter.  Inside those methods you can manipulate your object/data.  Look here:

```js
  private _data = '';

  @Input()
  set data(data: any) {
    this._data = data;
  }

  get data(): string { 
    console.log(_data) // <-------- you will see your data here
    return this._data; 
  }
}
```