# Angular 2 method returns different results when called in ngOnInit verse a button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm building a web site using the Angular 2 CLI, the page is a reactive form, and I've created a method called addQuestion() that is called in ngOnInit.  When it is ran that way it works as I'd like, adding a Question object with and array of answers.  When I run the same method from a button press, from the page it adds a Question object without the array of answers attached.  I've highlighted the line that is not working correctly.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

To be more clear, the method:

1. Creates a Question object
2. Then creates 4 answer objects and adds them to the Question object
3. Then pushes the Question object into a Questions array

When I run this method from ngOnIt it creates the full Question object with the embedded answers array (filled with 4 answers) and adds it to the questions array.

When I run the method from a button press on the page itself with:

```
<a href="" (click)="addQuestion()">Add Question</a>
```

it adds the Question object, but with a empty answers array.  I added an arrow below to where I think the error is occurring.  I added some console log commands right before this line and they show that they answers are getting added correctly, but after this push it's like they disappear.  I'm thinking this is some sort of scope error, but I'm too much of a junior developer to figure it out on my own.

```
export class QuestionListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('quizForm')
  public quizForm: FormGroup;

  @Input('questions')
  public questions: Question[];

  nextId: number;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  // <previous> 1. Create FormGroup quizForm
  // <previous> 2. Add Quiz controls to FormGroup (via toFormGroup)
  // 3. Add questions FormArray to FormGroup
  // 4. Add first Question to questions FormArray

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Initializing question list', this.questions);
    this.nextId = 1;
    this.quizForm.addControl('questions', new FormArray([]));
    this.addQuestion();
  }

  //_.uniqueId(),
  private getNextId(): number{
    return this.nextId++
  }

  addQuestion() {
    const question: Question = {
        id: this.getNextId(),
        title: 'My Question',
        instructions: 'Instructions here',
        time: 30000,
        answerId: 1,
        answers: []
    };

    for(var i=1;i<=4;i++){
      const a: Answer = {
        id: i,
        data: "Answer #" + i.toString(),
        type: "TEXT"
      }
      question.answers.push(a);
    }
    console.log("question equals=" + question);
    console.log("question answer 2 data = " + question.answers[1].data);

    this.questions.push(question); <--- This is the error line of code
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    return false;
  }
```

---

Edit:  An additional piece of information.  I based my code on this [excellent Reactive Forms tutorial](http://brophy.org/post/nested-reactive-forms-in-angular2), and in his code he used interfaces instead of classes.  I don't have a lot of experience with interfaces so I'm wondering if this is important to my situation.  Here's the interfaces:

```
export interface Question {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  instructions: string;  
  time: number;  // The number of Milliseconds the question will be shown
  answerId: number; //the array id of the correct answer
  answers?: Answer[];
}

export interface Answer {
  id: number;
  data: string;
  type: string; // to be enum AnswerType in the future
}
```

I'll try switching them to classes and see if that solves my problem.  Here is the HTML code, as I suspect the problem might be here as well.

```
<div [formGroup]="quizForm">
  <div formArrayName="questions">
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let idx=index">
      Question {{question.id}} (<a href="" (click)="removeQuestion(idx)">Remove</a>)
      <app-question-form [questions]="quizForm.controls.questions" [question]="question">
      </app-question-form>
    </div>
    <a href="" (click)="addQuestion()">Add Question</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Edit: More clues.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376856/angular2-passing-data-object-between-components) asks about a similar problem, and the answer to that question says "You will not be able to access this input inside Component Two's contractor, only inside its "ngOnInit". See this for reference".  If that's true, it's the first time I've heard of it.  I thought that was the reason for the Input decorator/annotation, was to pass objects between components.

Comment: what is the errror

Comment: @szaske Without the error message it is impossible to help you. Show all the log.

Comment: where are you initialize the questions array?

Comment: I'm passing it in from the parent component.  You can see the code as 

    @Input('questions')
      public questions: Question[];

Comment: There is an error in debuger console?

Comment: no there is no error in the console, it's just acting differently, and I cannot figure out how to get the method to act like it does when called by ngOnInit.

Comment: Have you tried, `this.questions.concat(question);` or `this.questions = [...this.questions, question ];` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the keyword let instead of const for your variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your `questions` is null or undefined whatever you define the type whiich is `Question[]` , so it call `null` then didn't include the method of `push` so error is throw.

```
@Input('questions')
  public questions: Question[] = [];
```

Comment: this did not make a difference, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Could you show what you input `[questions]` in your questionComponent?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug, and I'll still admit I'm perplexed.  In the child component I was passing the object that was getting corrupted.  The object was a Question object and it contained an array of answer objects and that list was called answers.  This Object was getting passed to the child using the @Input() decorator.  You can see the interface listed above.

My bug was that my answers array was getting destroyed or reset so it was empty when I called the method from the parent component.  So what was causing the problem?  In the child components ngOnInit() I was also creating another variable called answers.  Heres the line of code...

```
 this.questionForm.addControl('answers', new FormArray([]));
```

Which is a FormArray object and unrelated to the answers which is a property of a object I'm passing...but with this line in my code, my object gets corrupted...and the answers array gets wiped.  When I change the name of the FormArray to something other than 'answers' it works fine.

Is this a bug in Angular?