# ng2 component attributes confusion

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm having a hard problems getting an Angular 2 component to work in an Angular 1 app. I'm successfully bootstrapping the app using ngUpgrade, and my component shows up as expected, but there's some weirdness going on with binding.

Here's a representation of the component as used inside another Angular 1 directive:

```
<stdbutton name="name-{{someId}}"
           (click)="doSomething()"
           [highlighted]="true"
           [size]="small">Clicky</stdbutton>
```

`[highlighted]` and `[size]` are both intended to be used as optional attributes on the element.

As you can see, I use both ng1 and ng2 style bindings. The ng1 binding works fine - output HTML will have `name="name-12345"`. The weirdness is in the ng2 bindings:

- `(click)` doesn't execute the event handler
- `[highlighted]` is in a weird state
- `[size]` is always undefined

Here's the component definition:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'stdbutton',
    inputs: ['size', 'highlighted'],
    template: `
        <div [class]="buttonClass"
             [ngClass]="{stdbuttonhighlighted: highlighted}">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
        `
})
export class StdButtonComponent {
    @Input() size: any;
    @Input() highlighted: boolean;

    buttonClass: string;

    constructor() {
        this.buttonClass = 'stdbutton' + (this.size ? this.size : '');
        console.log(this.highlighted);
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

When I say that `[highlighted]` is in a weird state, here's what I mean. Look at the two `console.log` statements in the constructor. Now, the output:

```
stdbutton.component.ts:21 undefined

stdbutton.component.ts:22 
StdButtonComponent {buttonClass: "stdbutton"}
  buttonClass: "stdbutton"
  highlighted: true
  size: undefined
```

So, `this.highlighted` goes from `undefined` to `true` in between the two calls, and `this.size` remains `undefined` no matter what.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561845/angular2-cannot-access-inputs-from-my-controller-constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `[...]`, you will try to evaluate an expression based on the properties of the component. If you want to set the string "value" you can use either:

- `[size]="'small'"`
- `size="small"`

Comment: Okay, that gets me past the first hurdle. Thanks. However, I'm still confused by `this.size` having a seemingly ephemeral state.

    constructor() {
        this.buttonClass = 'stdbutton' + (this.size || '');
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.size);
    }

When I go to the browser console and expand StdButtonComponent, it's `size` property will be `"small"`. The second console.log will show `undefined`.