# Angular: Passing asynchronous data to child

Tags: angular, asynchronous, components

In my parent component I query my database for an array of `clients`:

```
this.clientService.get("/dashboard?start_date=2017-11-07", this.current_user.auth_token).subscribe(
    data => {
        this.clients = data
        console.log(data)
        loader.dismiss()
    },
    err => loader.dismiss()
)
```

My `clientService.get()` function is:

```
get(url, token):Observable<Response> {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("authentication", token );
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  let final_url = `${this.baseUrl}${url}`

  return this.http.get(final_url, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

and finally, my view is:

```
<approval-card *ngFor="let client of clients"
   [client]="client">
</approval-card>
```

In my child I call `client.name` and get an error because `client` is not yet defined.

```
export class ApprovalCardComponent {
  @Input() client: any;
  name: string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = this.client.name
  }
}
```

**How do I refactor to account for the asynchronous call to my server?**

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561845/angular2-cannot-access-inputs-from-my-controller-constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data from the inputs should be available at the ngOnInit lifecycle hook

```js
export class ApprovalCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() client: any;
  name: string;

  constructor() {
   
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
   this.name = this.client.name
  }
}
```

```js
this.observableClients = this.clientService.get("/dashboard?start_date=2017-11-07", this.current_user.auth_token);
```

```html
<approval-card *ngFor="let client of observableClients | async"
   [client]="client">
</approval-card>
```

The only issue you might have now is not being able to dismiss the loader.

Comment: I like this solution but I was wondering if there was a way to use the `async` pipe with my `Observable`

Comment: @JeremyThomas Then why didn't you try using async pipe?

Comment: @AmitChigadani I've tried, it never seems to be the right type and I'm new to `Observables`.  I have a response type, not an array

Comment: @JeremyThomas How does your response look? And also with `*ngFor` you should be using array not the `json` Object directly. First do `let res = data.json()` and then retrieve the array part for `clients` from `res`.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would drop one more answer. The order of component initialization goes like: `constructor -> OnChanges -> OnInit -> ...`.

Usually data passed from parent to child is available in `OnInit`, but in this case since this is async, it maybe doesn't have had time to be passed to child. So what you can do, except answers provided, is to use the `OnChanges`.. where taken from the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges)...

> Angular calls its `ngOnChanges()` method whenever it detects changes to *input properties* of the component (or directive)

So you can tap into that life cycle hook, but also needing to do a check that the `client` exists:

```ts
ngOnChanges() {
  if(this.client) {
    this.name = this.client.name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not wait until `clients` are resolved. And also you can use async pipe to wait for the observable.

```
<div *ngIf="clients">
    <approval-card *ngFor="let client of clients | async"
        [client]="client">
    </approval-card
</div>
```

As the other answer suggests here, go for `ngOnInit()` instead of `constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way is this :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="clients">
  <approval-card *ngFor="let client of clients"
    [client]="client">
  </approval-card>
</ng-container>
```